# ShieldUI Grid with remote data that is NOT oData

Tags: shieldui

Every remote virtualization demo show how to populate the grid but they all use oData.

Can someone help me figure out how to use standard JSON returned from my web service?  I have attempted to modify this demo with no success: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-virtualization/remote-data

The number, titles of the columns may be different per record, too...
(see: [ShieldUI Grid - Adding Columns at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154198/shieldui-grid-adding-columns-at-run-time))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This demo](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service) shows how you can populate data from a RESTful web service - take a look at the dataSource.remote.read option.

More info about this setting can be found in the [DataSource documentation](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource/javascript/api/settings/remote/read).

Comment: I don't need to modify any records, this is a read-only scenario. The on-demand modification necessary is to add/remove columns per the data being read, please see my other post listed above.